# WCF service not completely working and internal server error

Tags: c#, asp.net, wcf, database-connection

I am trying to create a WCF service in which people can add job vacancy in a database, database that is displayed in another webform.

My problem is that when I'm trying to display my webform I get this error :

> Server intern error: the connection hasn't been established because the targeted computer refused it.
>
> Description: An exception non handled happened while executing the actual web query.
>
> Details:  System.Net.Sockets.SocketException no connection allowed because the targeted computer refused it
>
> Source :
>
> [System.ComponentModel.EditorBrowsableAttribute(System.ComponentModel.EditorBrowsableState.Advanced)]
>       Service.GetAllJobsResponse Service.IService.GetAllJobs(Service.GetAllJobsRequest request) {
>       return base.Channel.GetAllJobs(request);
>       }

My research tells me it was maybe that my localhost just changed its address but I check that and it was teh same. Then my lecturer spent 1h on my pc without finding any solutions. Maybe it is linked with my WCF service which seems to have something wrong in it.

I'm posting here the picture of the error maybe there is :

[image]

The translation of the white square : this operation couldn't be handled by the test WCF client because the operation is using the GetAllJobsResponse type.

This is the code in my file `IService.cs` :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.Serialization;
using System.ServiceModel;
using System.Text;

// REMARQUE : vous pouvez utiliser la commande Renommer du menu Refactoriser pour changer le nom d'interface "IService" à la fois dans le code et le fichier de configuration.
[ServiceContract]
public interface IService
{
    [OperationContract]
    void DoWork();

    [OperationContract]
    DataSet.TableDataTable GetAllJobs();

    [OperationContract]
    DataSet.TableDataTable GetAJobs(int ID);

    [OperationContract]
    void AddJob(string title, string salary, string benefits, string keywords, string jobtype, string location, DateTime startDate, string description, string recruitmentAgency, string agencyContact, string agencyTel, string agencyEmail, string jobRef, DateTime datePosted, DateTime dateExpire);

    [OperationContract]
    DataSet.Table1DataTable testJobs();

}
```

And here is the code of my file `Service.cs` :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.Serialization;
using System.ServiceModel;
using System.Text;

// REMARQUE : vous pouvez utiliser la commande Renommer du menu Refactoriser pour changer le nom de classe "Service" à la fois dans le code, le fichier svc et le fichier de configuration.
public class Service : IService
{
    public void DoWork()
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public DataSet.TableDataTable GetAllJobs()
    {
        DataSetTableAdapters.TableTableAdapter ta = new DataSetTableAdapters.TableTableAdapter();
        return ta.GetData();    
    }

    public DataSet.TableDataTable GetAJobs(int ID)
    {
       DataSetTableAdapters.TableTableAdapter ta = new DataSetTableAdapters.TableTableAdapter();
       return ta.GetDataByID(ID);    
    }

    public void AddJob(string title, string salary, string benefits, string keywords, string jobtype, string location, DateTime startDate, string description, string recruitmentAgency, string agencyContact, string agencyTel, string agencyEmail, string jobRef, DateTime datePosted, DateTime dateExpire)
    {
            DataSetTableAdapters.TableTableAdapter ta = new DataSetTableAdapters.TableTableAdapter();
            ta.Insert(title, salary, benefits, keywords, jobtype, location, startDate, description, recruitmentAgency, agencyContact, agencyTel, agencyEmail, jobRef, datePosted, dateExpire);
    }

    public DataSet.Table1DataTable testJobs()
    {
        DataSetTableAdapters.Table1TableAdapter ta = new DataSetTableAdapters.Table1TableAdapter();
        return ta.GetAllData();
    }
}
```

If you need any other code (`web.config`, `webform.apsx.cs` or database please just let me know). 
Hoping you can help.

EDIT :
This is my webservice 'web.config' :

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!--
  Pour plus d'informations sur la configuration de votre application ASP.NET, consultez
  http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=169433
  -->
<configuration>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="DatabaseConnectionString" connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\Database.mdf;Integrated Security=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
  </connectionStrings>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5"/>
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5"/>
  </system.web>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="">
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpsGetEnabled="true"/>
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false"/>
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true"/>
  </system.serviceModel>
  <!-- <endpoint address="http://localhost:43988/Service.svc" binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="countrySoap" contract="ServCountry.countrySoap" name="countrySoap"/> -->
</configuration>
```

I post here my webform 'web.config' :

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!--
  Pour plus d'informations sur la configuration de votre application ASP.NET, consultez
  http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=169433
  -->
<configuration>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5"/>
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5"/>
  </system.web>
  <appSettings/>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
      <basicHttpBinding>
        <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_IService" />
      </basicHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <client>
      <endpoint address="http://localhost:43988/Service.svc" binding="basicHttpBinding"
        bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_IService" contract="Service.IService"
        name="BasicHttpBinding_IService" />
    </client>
  </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
<!--wcf web service : http://localhost:45317/ -->
```

If you still need other piece of code, just ask 
Mayeul

Comment: most likely the config (endpoints, bindings) are mismatched between client and host. Show us ServiceModel sections of both configs.

Comment: I've put the code of my 2 webconfig. What do you mean by ServiceModel ? Is it the .svc file ?

Comment: by ServiceModel, I mean the <system.serviceModel> elements in the config file. I think your configuration should work, you don't have a service endpoint defined but it will setup a default basisHttpBinding in that case. Make sure your WCF host is running before the client tries to make a request.

Comment: One of my friends told me that when he ran not on IIS it resolved the GetAllJobsResponse type problem. But I haven't found how to launch it on the visual intern server (i think it is the second option)

Comment: It is the WCF Test Client that cannot handle receiving complex types, it is not a problem with IIS. You need to start your host (wcf service), and then start your client website. They cannot both be running on the same port so make sure they are on different ports.

Comment: I've tried to modify the port but I can't find the 'web' folder in the properties panel so I am blocked right know ...

Comment: This is one difference between web application projects and web site projects. You can change the port by editing the .sln file. Close Visual Studio, open the solution file in a text editor, then change all references to the port. Of course, I can't tell if this is even your problem but if you need to change the port that is how you can do it.